Ubuntu having intermittent lag on Dynabook-TECRA
The issue :
I am experiencing some intermittent lag on my Dynabook TECRA-X50. The mouse and keyboard would have intermittent "freezing" making the use of the computer almost impossible.
This lag starts randomly : sometimes I can work OK for days, other times it's there right when I reboot.
It use to affect my computer only when I would try to suspend it but rebooting it would make it work normally again. But not anymore : now I can reboot it 10 times before finally having a "normal" mouse/keyboard experience
What I tried
Mostly, I got help from chatGPT and tried the following :

I updated all my packages

Setting my Ubuntu power settings to "performance"

In the system monitor, I see that one of the CPU shows regular "cycles" from 0 to 100% back to 0. This is a perfect curve and it keeps on cycling forever. This could linked to my issue ?


When displaying $ top the top process with 70+% of CPU is "kworker/2:3+events_long" no idea what this is

I ran perf for 10 seconds and got the following report


Then I check the ACPI interrupt numbers. I got 161716 counts on gpe6E. This could mean I have compatibility issue with some of my laptop's hardware...but which ?



Have you checked journalctl? So lets say it's currently 1:30 AM and the problem started like 10 minutes ago. sudo journalctl -S 1:00 will show the logs since 1AM. If you notice something different in the logs closer to the time when the problem started (closer to 1:20 or 1:30) that might indicate what the issue is. A few times, I've had usb cables or devices attached that the system didn't like and were causing similar problems.
